# "Does not name a type" error when using enum inside Pimpl idiom

Tags: c++

This is a code sample:

foo.h

```
class Foo 
{
    .............
    class Bar;
    Bar* pimpl;
};
```

foo.cpp

```
class Foo::Bar
{
    enum class PositionsEnum : int
    {
        Extended, Retracted
    };
    void MoveToPosition(PositionsEnum pos);
    PositionsEnum GetPosition();
};

void Foo::Bar::MoveToPosition(PositionsEnum  pos) {}

PositionsEnum Foo::Bar::GetPosition() {}
```

On the `GetPosition` method I get a  `error: 'PositionsEnum ' does not name a type`.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Note that the `enum class` definition needs a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefix PositionsEnum with the class

```
Foo::Bar::PositionsEnum Foo::Bar::GetPosition() {}
```

Comment: `auto Foo::Bar::GetPosition() -> PositionsEnum {}`

Comment: @vBx Post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @chris This only works for C++11, but the question was posted with C++ tag.

Comment: @Jens, To my knowledge the C++ tag implies C++11. Either way, no harm no foul if C++11 isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
class Bar
```

with

```
class Foo::Bar
```

---

Addendum: and now that you've fixed the first error, also fix the next one in a reasonable, non-verbose way. Namely, replace

```
PositionsEnum Foo::Bar::GetPosition() {}
```

which doesn't compile, with

```
auto Foo::Bar::GetPosition() -> PositionsEnum {}
```

which does compile.

The difference is which scope `PositionsEnum` is looked up in.

Comment: I am already doing this, I will update the code.(inside foo.cpp)